# Multicast message not received by client

Tags: node.js, linux, udp, multicast, tcpdump

With tcpdump I see these Multicast messages on ETH0:

```
19:50:31.493386 IP 169.254.17.110.60000 > 239.1.0.8.60000: UDP, length 273
19:50:31.493962 IP 169.254.17.110.60000 > 239.1.0.8.60000: UDP, length 153
```

But I don't receive them with a client program. I tried Python and NodeJS:

```
const PORT = 60000;
const HOST = '10.100.0.1';
const MCAST = '239.1.0.8';

const dgram = require('dgram');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
client.bind({address: HOST, port: PORT}, () => {
    const address = client.address();
    console.log('UDP Client listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
    client.setBroadcast(true);
    client.setMulticastTTL(128);
    client.addMembership(MCAST, HOST);
});

client.on('message', (message, remote) => {
    console.log('From: ' + remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);
});
```

My ETH0 IP is 10.100.0.1. I tried not binding to my HOST w/o success.

If I send me a Multicast message with another NodeJS script to the same address and port (239.1.0.8:60000) it's received with my client program.

I'm working on Debian Stretch:

```
Linux car 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for any guidance on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch errors with

```js
client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I do already, just omitted these lines for simplicity. No errors.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471680/udp-multicast-client-does-not-see-udp-multicast-traffic-generated-by-tcpreplay/22654434#22654434