# replaying multicast UDP packet capture via tcpreplay not being seen by client

Tags: udp, multicast, tcpreplay

I'm having no joy in getting a replayed UDP Multicast packet to be "seen" by a client program on a different machine.

Details:
I have two machines on my local (wired) network connected through one unmanaged switch. One machine (running **tcpreplay**) is running Ubuntu 20.04, the other machine is running Windows 10.

On the Windows machine I have a Python program I wrote which listens for UDP multicast packets on port 5110 (this is dictated by the source of the UDP stream which is a commercial program). When I run the commercial program, my Python code correctly consumes the incoming packets and all seems to be working fine. I have a lot of work yet to do on the contents of those packets after they are received, but that isn't important for this issue.

So, moving forward, I decided it would be great to be able to work on the Python code without having the commercial program always running in the background hogging up resources. I figured if I could catch a snippet of UDP broadcasts from that program, I should be able to replay at leisure without having to run that resource hog.

So, on the Windows machine, I captured a UDP multicast packet stream using **Wireshark** and saved to a *pcap* file which I then copied to the Ubuntu machine.

I then attempted to replay that *pcap* file (on the Ubuntu machine) as follows:
`$sudo tcpreplay -i enp5s0 single.pcap`

To my disappointment, my Python program (on the Windows machine) did not receive the incoming packets.

Back on the Windows machine, I fired up **Wireshark** again and captured the "replayed" packet coming from the Ubuntu machine - so it appears the packet did make it out of my Ubuntu machine and into my Windows one. The contents of both the source packet (sent by **tcpreplay**) and the received packet (grabbed by **Wireshark**) appear identical - including the source and destination MAC addresses and the checksums. A diff on the byte contents of each packet yields no differences.

However, my Python program still stoically sits there waiting at:

```
data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

Here on stackoverflow, I did find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471680/udp-multicast-client-does-not-see-udp-multicast-traffic-generated-by-tcpreplay) which seems to be an identical problem, however none of the solutions presented within helped (including changing the rp_filter parameter). I also saw mention of a Windows program, "**Colasoft PacketPlayer**", which I tried - running on the same machine as my Python client. This appears to have the same apparent results (i.e. no joy). I did not initially try that route as I was concerned with generating the packet on the same machine which is listening for it. (As an aside, I did also capture the replayed packet from **Colasoft PacketPlayer** and it too appears identical to the source packet).

At this point I'm out of ideas and am reaching out to the community for possible next steps?

Comment: After posting this initial question, I went ahead and wrote a Python program on the Ubuntu machine which did a multicast send of a small packet. This WAS received by the Windows Python client, so it appears the Ubuntu machine along with my network topology is able to support the multicast send.